# How to write a python script to interact with shell scripts

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, nonblocking, python-interactive

I encountered a problem in work. Here it is.

I have several scripts(mostly are shell scripts) to execute, and I want to write a python script to run them automatically. One of these shell scripts needs **interactive input** during it's execution. What troubled me is that I can't find a way to read its input prompt, so I can't decide what to enter to continue.

I simplified the problem to something like this:

There is a script named `mediator.py`, which run `greeter.sh` inside. The `mediator` takes `greeter`'s input prompt and print it to the user, then gets user's input and pass it to `greeter`. The `mediator` needs to act exactly the same as the `greeter` from user's point of view.

Here is `greeter.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Please enter your name: " # <- I want 'mediator.py' to read this prompt and show it to me, and then get what I input, then pass my input to 'greeter.sh'
read name 
echo "Hello, " $name
```

I want to do this in the following order:

1. The user (that's me) run `mediator.py`
2. The `mediator` run `greeter.sh` inside
3. The `mediator` **get the input prompt of `greeter`**, and output it on the screen.*(At this time, the `greeter` is waiting for user's input. This is the main problem I stuck with)*
4. The user input a string (for example, 'Mike'), `mediator` get the string 'Mike' and transmit it to `greeter`
5. The `greeter` get the name 'Mike', and print a greeting
6. The `mediator` get the greeting, and output it on the screen.

I searched for some solution and determined to use `Popen` function in `subprocess` module with `stdout` of sub-process directed to `PIPE`, it's something like this:

```
sb = subprocess.Popen(['sh', 'greeter.sh'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = stdout, stderr = stdout)
```

but I can't solve the main problem in **step 3** above. Can anyone give me some advice for help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You make it much more complicated (and brittle) than it has to be. Instead of coding everything at the top-level and try to use subprocess or whatever to use your scripts as if they where functions, just write modules and functions and use them from your main script.

Here's an example with all contained in the script itself, but you can split it into distinct modules if you need to share some functions between different scripts

```
# main.py
def ask_name():
    return raw_input("Please enter your name: ")

def greet(name):
    return "Hello, {} name !\n".format(name)

def main():
    name = ask_name()
    print greet(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. I came up with this usage scenario beacuse I   met it in work. I have several shell scripts to run, and I want to write a python script to run them automatically. One of these shell scripts needs user to enter some options during it's exexuting, so I need to get the prompt of the shell script and then determine which option to input for continuing execution. That's it.

Comment: You should edit your question with this context then - that's a somehow different problem. Which I'll leave to a `subprocess` expert FWIW...

Comment: Thanks~ The question has been re-described now.

Comment: I removed the previous `greeter.py` code and rewrote it to `greeter.sh` using shell script, so it became more correspondent to my usage scenario